# What is this buildpack error?

Tags: heroku, create-react-app, buildpack

I am trying to deploy a react app bootstrapped with create-react-app to heroku. The build keeps failing, and I get this error on the command line and in the build log

```
 App not compatible with buildpack: 
 https://github.com/AdamT213/RateYourAcquaintance.git
   bash:
```

/app/tmp/buildpacks/85d7c3f242750d8981190d9ed3f29461a37d776664b86f3dc3263563e08c29443b03b01355b70cb2a4a461abab934f47aa7919c42b019918961b2ebf902b1fa/bin/detect
 No such file or directory
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection- 
       failure
       !     Push failed

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see now. I was trying to set my app's url as the buildpack, when I really need this url: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git. Makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

I would also advise checking what files the gitignore file are ignoring. In particular, the "BUILD" folder needs to not be ignored (and it seems it is by default for me)