# Deploying React app to Heroku fails error message "App not compatible with buildpack"

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, deployment, react-redux

I am trying to deploy a create-react-app to Heroku using my Github repository but I keep receiving this failed error when I deploy:

"-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/myappname/myWebsite.git
       bash: /app/tmp/buildpacks/37ed7dcef0d74398ac56add743d1b21da65705805e483325eac5f7b0d4b7437ae2907af6ab6df9bd1b996f869fee5ee8c1a4984f44fe6d8051b8e2e7e2665ca8/bin/detect: No such file or directory
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed"

This is the first time I am deploying a react application to Heroku so if anyone can help me with this error it will be nice.

Answer (score 5):

Change the buildpack URL to: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git

I had this error too and this fixed it.

See original solution here: [What is this buildpack error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612729/what-is-this-buildpack-error?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

check the buildpack URL and use this: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git

and kindly check inside the repository there should be no other folder except the React app folder. I was facing this problem because I was having readme.md file in the repository along with React app folder.